# Using NetBeans UI designer, how can I copy UI components from one project and paste them into another?

Tags: java, swing, merge, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans 7.4.  I've created a new UI using the designer.  I would like to use a old UI design from another project in this new project, "cutting and pasting" all the components from the old design's JFrame and inserting them into the new design's JPanel.

Does NetBeans provide any method to do this in the design tool rather than the source?  I'm hesitant to edit the generated code, having corrupted designs in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is in a separate class, a possible solution is to import the component from the old project with the Palette Manager.

Menu: Tools => Palette => Swing/AWT Components => Add from Project

The component will be available in the Palette.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to add anything from the old project.

Comment: Can you give some more hints? Aren't you able to see the old components in the palette?

Answer (score 0):

Open the design tab of the frame you want to copy, then hold Shift and drag the mouse over all the design elements.

You can then copy them all and paste in another JFrame.